# Solving differential equation and obtain expressions with unknowns?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I have the following differential equation

$my'' + \beta y' + mg = 0$ , with condition $y(0)=0$.

I need to solve the equation and obtain expressions for $y(t)$ and $y'(t)$.

I have attempted to use the try method of substituting in $y=e^{\lambda t}$ but do not know how to proceed beyond that.

The differential equation is meant to represent free-fall of an object with air resistance that is proportional to it's speed.

Comment: The answer is [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=linear+differential+equation+second+order+constant+coefficients&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=iBkbVqjgKafu8we7zq_wBA).

Comment: Have you tried taking derivatives of your $y(t) = e^{\lambda t}$ function and substituting back into the desired differential equation?  When you do that, the idea then is to find one or more $\lambda$ values that work.

Comment: $y(t)=e^{λt}$ does not satisfy $y(0)=0$

Answer (score 0):

The equation is a second-order linear, inhomogenous ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients. You can accept or search after it, but the general solution can be given in the form $y(t) = y_h (t) + y_p (t)$, where $y_h (t)$ is called the solution to the homogeneous differential equation (homogeneous means there is no constant term in the equation, in this example the $mg$ term), while $y_p(t)$ is called one particular solution to the original (inhomogeneous) equation.

Beginning with $y_h (t)$:

\begin{equation}
my'' + \beta y' =0,
\end{equation}
This is the homogeneous differential equation. If you substitute $e^{\lambda t}$, you can get the value of $\lambda$ (which should not depend on t, of course). This comes from the fact that $\frac{d}{dt} e^t = e^t$. You'll get
\begin{equation}
\text{something} \cdot e^{\lambda t} = 0,
\end{equation}
and as it is valid for any t (and it is never 0), you can divide by $e^{\lambda t}$. You will get 2 possible $\lambda$-s, you will need both: $y_h (t) = C_1 \cdot e^{\lambda_1 t}+ C_2 \cdot e^{\lambda_2 t}$.

For $y_p(t)$, you only need **one** particular solution. If you see one immediately, in any form, you are lucky. I suggest looking for a solution of the form $y_p (t) = A + Bt$.

Once you got $y_h$ and $y_p$, you simply add the two together and get the general solution. Finally, use the initial conditions to determine the two constants.